# Is there an equivalent Scala library (i.e., open source) to Scala's JavaConverters that does not use Wrappers?

Tags: scala, jsf

I'm currently using Scala with JSF, of which the two play pretty well together. However at times JSF needs to re-instantiate (via Class.newInstance) a data structure, like a list. For example in a managed bean I have:

```
@BeanProperty
var countries: java.util.List[String] = List("US").asJava
```

Which works fine until you get to JSF's process validation phase where it runs into java.lang.InstantiationException:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: scala.collection.JavaConversions$SeqWrapper
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.createCollection(MenuRenderer.java:906)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:366)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:128)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:314)
at org.primefaces.component.selectcheckboxmenu.SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.java:34)
...
```

From a fundamental level it makes sense that Wrappers may not be re-instantiated from scratch, so using JavaConverters won't work well here. My question is there library that already provides a complete Data Structure mapping/conversion without wrappers? If not I'll just write my own internal ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Java `ArrayList` as the `var` and then use `JavaConverters`/`JavaConversions` in your code to manipulate.  That's the usual approach I use for APIs like Hibernate, JAX-WS, JSR-303, etc. that need Java collections.

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

@BeanProperty
var countries: java.util.List[String] = new java.util.ArrayList[String] += "US"
```

or

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

@BeanProperty
var countries: java.util.List[String] = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
countries.asScala += "US"
countries.asScala ++= List("US", "MX")
```

If you really want to just convert back and forth and not wrap it's easy enough without creating your own classes:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

@BeanProperty
var countries: java.util.List[String] = new java.util.ArrayList[String]

val countriesBuff = new ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
countriesBuff ++= countries.asScala     // Convert from ArrayList to ArrayBuffer
// ...
countries.addAll(countriesBuff.asJava)  // Convert the other direction
```

But then you have to worry about the cost of copying and about when synchronization needs to happen.  Wrapping/decorating just a lot more convenient.

Comment: I agree that single line of code is a nice elegant approach. However my concern with importing JavaConversions within a Scala file is that it could lead to excessive conversions (i.e., because it's implicit). I should have stipulated that I was avoiding JavaConversions.

Comment: You can use JavaConverters instead, which requires you to be explicit.  See added example.

Comment: Yes that's what I was using above, only I started with a Scala List. The 2nd way is not a bad suggestion, it's just loses some of the Scala conciseness since it cannot be done in 1 statement, hence my question for an alternative to JavaConverters. If I write my own full conversion decorators I can create something like `var countries: java.util.List[String] = List("US", "MX").toJavaList` (i.e., using the same pattern found in the JavaConverters.scala). I was just hoping there was an existing library that already provides full data structure conversions decorators rather than wrappers.

Comment: I've added a bit to the answer re: converting versus wrapping.

Comment: The one big gotcha (in my book) with JavaConversions is with maps and get(). It will use the Java get() not the Scala get().  It's confusing which is why it is recommended to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This was a good discussion. I agree the wrappers are better 9 times out of 10. This was just one case where full conversion might be useful (i.e., only a one time conversion cost for readability sake). Either way, I think there's enough useful content here to mark the question answered.